# How would I turn a flat array with parentId into a tree?

Tags: javascript

I have an array with `id` and `parentId` and I need to create a tree out of this flat array so that each `parentId` that matches an `id` is now a child under `comments`

It's basically a threaded comment list.

```
{
  "comments": [
    {
      "body": "asdf",
      "createdAt": "2022-11-15T17:53:05.048Z",
      "createdBy": {
        "id": "user:34nrxg022jt61t3xecgx",
        "username": "asdf"
      },
      "id": "comments:fmd0noccuj",
      "parentId": "comments:yxbc3jv4yp",
      "postId": "posts:j6uzaypl61",
      "updatedAt": "2022-11-15T17:53:05.048Z"
    },
    {
      "body": "asdf",
      "createdAt": "2022-11-15T17:51:36.154Z",
      "createdBy": {
        "id": "user:34nrxg022jt61t3xecgx",
        "username": "asdf"
      },
      "id": "comments:gfanwk4r1d",
      "parentId": null,
      "postId": "posts:j6uzaypl61",
      "updatedAt": "2022-11-15T17:51:36.154Z"
    },
    {
      "body": {},
      "createdAt": "2022-11-15T17:48:38.321Z",
      "createdBy": {
        "id": "user:34nrxg022jt61t3xecgx",
        "username": "asdf"
      },
      "id": "comments:0atvept3ob",
      "parentId": null,
      "postId": "posts:j6uzaypl61",
      "updatedAt": "2022-11-15T17:48:38.321Z"
    },
    {
      "body": {},
      "createdAt": "2022-11-15T17:45:45.008Z",
      "createdBy": {
        "id": "user:34nrxg022jt61t3xecgx",
        "username": "asdf"
      },
      "id": "comments:kiqco3uexk",
      "parentId": null,
      "postId": "posts:j6uzaypl61",
      "updatedAt": "2022-11-15T17:45:45.008Z"
    },
    {
      "body": {},
      "createdAt": "2022-11-15T17:44:34.587Z",
      "createdBy": {
        "id": "user:34nrxg022jt61t3xecgx",
        "username": "asdf"
      },
      "id": "comments:gs641tos5h",
      "parentId": null,
      "postId": "posts:j6uzaypl61",
      "updatedAt": "2022-11-15T17:44:34.587Z"
    },
    {
      "body": "Test2",
      "createdAt": "2022-11-15T10:14:24.119Z",
      "createdBy": {
        "id": "user:34nrxg022jt61t3xecgx",
        "username": "asdf"
      },
      "id": "comments:yxbc3jv4yp",
      "parentId": null,
      "postId": "posts:j6uzaypl61",
      "updatedAt": "2022-11-15T10:14:24.119Z"
    },
    {
      "body": "test",
      "createdAt": "2022-11-15T10:09:13.370Z",
      "createdBy": {
        "id": "user:34nrxg022jt61t3xecgx",
        "username": "asdf"
      },
      "id": "comments:1llogp6a7t",
      "parentId": null,
      "postId": "posts:j6uzaypl61",
      "updatedAt": "2022-11-15T10:09:13.370Z"
    },
    {
      "body": "test",
      "createdAt": "2022-11-15T10:07:22.243Z",
      "createdBy": {
        "id": "user:34nrxg022jt61t3xecgx",
        "username": "asdf"
      },
      "id": "comments:xqrk9bfp0h",
      "parentId": null,
      "postId": "posts:j6uzaypl61",
      "updatedAt": "2022-11-15T10:07:22.243Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is what I have but it returns an empty array if there are top level comments with no `parentId`:

```
const data = await res.json();

const nest = (items, id = null, link = 'parentId') =>
    items
        .filter((item) => (item[link] ? item[link] === id : false))
        .map((item) => ({ ...item, children: nest(items, item.id) }));

this.comments = nest(data.comments);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a map of commentID -> comment, then iterate over each comment, and if it has a parentID add it to comments[parentID].comments, and delete it from the top level map, then get the values from the map:

```js
const data = {
  "comments": [
    {
      "body": "asdf",
      "createdAt": "2022-11-15T17:53:05.048Z",
      "createdBy": {
        "id": "user:34nrxg022jt61t3xecgx",
        "username": "asdf"
      },
      "id": "comments:fmd0noccuj",
      "parentId": "comments:yxbc3jv4yp",
      "postId": "posts:j6uzaypl61",
      "updatedAt": "2022-11-15T17:53:05.048Z"
    },
    {
      "body": "asdf",
      "createdAt": "2022-11-15T17:51:36.154Z",
      "createdBy": {
        "id": "user:34nrxg022jt61t3xecgx",
        "username": "asdf"
      },
      "id": "comments:gfanwk4r1d",
      "parentId": null,
      "postId": "posts:j6uzaypl61",
      "updatedAt": "2022-11-15T17:51:36.154Z"
    },
    {
      "body": {},
      "createdAt": "2022-11-15T17:48:38.321Z",
      "createdBy": {
        "id": "user:34nrxg022jt61t3xecgx",
        "username": "asdf"
      },
      "id": "comments:0atvept3ob",
      "parentId": null,
      "postId": "posts:j6uzaypl61",
      "updatedAt": "2022-11-15T17:48:38.321Z"
    },
    {
      "body": {},
      "createdAt": "2022-11-15T17:45:45.008Z",
      "createdBy": {
        "id": "user:34nrxg022jt61t3xecgx",
        "username": "asdf"
      },
      "id": "comments:kiqco3uexk",
      "parentId": null,
      "postId": "posts:j6uzaypl61",
      "updatedAt": "2022-11-15T17:45:45.008Z"
    },
    {
      "body": {},
      "createdAt": "2022-11-15T17:44:34.587Z",
      "createdBy": {
        "id": "user:34nrxg022jt61t3xecgx",
        "username": "asdf"
      },
      "id": "comments:gs641tos5h",
      "parentId": null,
      "postId": "posts:j6uzaypl61",
      "updatedAt": "2022-11-15T17:44:34.587Z"
    },
    {
      "body": "Test2",
      "createdAt": "2022-11-15T10:14:24.119Z",
      "createdBy": {
        "id": "user:34nrxg022jt61t3xecgx",
        "username": "asdf"
      },
      "id": "comments:yxbc3jv4yp",
      "parentId": null,
      "postId": "posts:j6uzaypl61",
      "updatedAt": "2022-11-15T10:14:24.119Z"
    },
    {
      "body": "test",
      "createdAt": "2022-11-15T10:09:13.370Z",
      "createdBy": {
        "id": "user:34nrxg022jt61t3xecgx",
        "username": "asdf"
      },
      "id": "comments:1llogp6a7t",
      "parentId": null,
      "postId": "posts:j6uzaypl61",
      "updatedAt": "2022-11-15T10:09:13.370Z"
    },
    {
      "body": "test",
      "createdAt": "2022-11-15T10:07:22.243Z",
      "createdBy": {
        "id": "user:34nrxg022jt61t3xecgx",
        "username": "asdf"
      },
      "id": "comments:xqrk9bfp0h",
      "parentId": null,
      "postId": "posts:j6uzaypl61",
      "updatedAt": "2022-11-15T10:07:22.243Z"
    }
  ]
}

const comments = data.comments.reduce((carry, current) => {
    carry[current.id] = { ...current, comments: [] }
    return carry;
}, {});


Object.values(comments).forEach((c) => {
    if (c.parentId !== null && comments[c.parentId]) {
        comments[c.parentId].comments.push(c);
    }
});

Object.values(comments).forEach((c) => {
    if (c.parentId !== null && comments[c.parentId]) {
       delete(comments[c.id])
    }
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(Object.values(comments), ' ', 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const createDataTree = (dataset) => {
                    let hashTable = Object.create(null);
                    dataset.forEach((aData) => (hashTable[aData.id] = { ...aData, children: [] }));
                    let dataTree = [];
                    dataset.forEach((aData) => {
                        if (aData.parentId) hashTable[aData.parentId].children.push(hashTable[aData.id]);
                        else dataTree.push(hashTable[aData.id]);
                    });
                    return dataTree;
                };
```